# setting up a wifi lan with no connection to the Internet

Tags: wifi, local-area-network

(apologies: I'm a beginner with networks. And I don't know if I have chosen the right stackexchange category.)

Here's the situation. We are organizing an event in a big room with no Internet connection. Some of the activities will rely on web apps that we designed and will run on an Ipad that has WIFI but no GSM. I put them on a web page. There is 4G cellphone service via the town's antennas, that we could use via a cellphone that would share its connection with the Ipad using WIFI, but I would like to have a backup solution: to run on a desktop a local server that is not accessible from the Internet (completely disconnected from the Internet), and that one can link to, using WIFI.

It would have other advantages that I won't detail here, and also I could use such networks in other useful situations. I have a router (Dual band WLAN AP Concurent Gigabit 2.4G and 5G, 3T3R MIMO 450Mbps Router, IEEE 802.11a/n/g/b, it says, and I do not understand some of the words here). I have not succeeded in finding the right keywords to type in Google to find explanations on how to make this work. My current attempts at following the web pages I have found have not resulted in functionning situations. Any help appreciated.

Currently :

- I can run a server on the PC (Windows 10) with EasyPHP Server
- I tried plugging the PC to the router via an ethernet cable on on the router's plug called LAN1 and also on the one called WLAN.
- I tried the settings "gateway" and also the one called "bridge" on the router. However what this precisely means eludes me.
- I can have the router emit a WIFI network with password
- I can have the Ipad connect to the WIFI network
- I /think/ I have opened the appropriate ports in Windows' Firewall
- I am using an antivirus but no firewall (other than Windows')
- When typing the server's IP address in the web browser on the Ipad I get either no connection or a refused connection, depending on the various settings (which I do not remember)

Maybe my approach is completely wrong and cannot work?

How can one diagnose the reason(s) for a refused connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work, here were the steps, as far as I remember them:

Note: in several steps, one has to wait from seconds to minutes, for the change to take effect.

- Connect a computer (not necessarily the one hosting the server) to the LAN1 ethernet plug of the router with an RJ45 cable. This is how I can access and modify the settings of my router (check with your own router's instructions: I then have to open a browser and type the URL 127.0.0.1:10000)
- Setup the router to broadcast a password protected WIFI network.
- Normally it should use DHCP (auto) by default. If not, correct this with the settings (look this up on the Internet, I did not have to do it).
- Set the router to use Gateway mode, if not already in this mode.

It may be necessary to fix the IP address of the computer hosting the network, here is how:

- On the computer hosting the server (it may be the same), connect to the WIFI that you set up above.
- On the router's settings one should be able to see the MAC address of the computer hosting the server. Copy this and use it in the next point.
- Set the router to give a fixed IP address to the MAC address of the computer hosting the server. On mine, it is in Internet Settings -> LAN -> Statically assigned (the last one is a pair of text fields, you put here the MAC address and some IP address that is within the range "start IP address" to "end IP address" of the DHCP of the router; I chose the first one, i.e. was 192.168.2.100).

Now the server :

Note: I chose EasyPhP for the server. But for security reasons, it is recommended (by EasyPhP themselves) to use another one. So apply the instructions below at your own risk.

- Install EasyPhP Webserver
- Restart computer (needed)
- Run EasyPhP Webserver
- In notification bar click EasyPhP icon and "open dashboard"
- A browser window opens. Click HttpServer. This opens a new page. There, click "install service".
- When the installation is finished, in the same browser page, choose "start service".
- If necessary, do the same with the PHP server. (In my case, I did not use PHP so I did not have to start the server).
- The page should tell you the IP address and port: 192.168.XXX.XXX:PPP. It says the port is PPP.
- If you fixed (by the instruction earlier) the IP address on the router's network of the MAC address of the computer hosting the server, you should see the same IP address here.
- In Windows open Control Panel -> Firewall -> advanced settings -> add incoming rule to open port PPP. Details of the rule : TCP, allow connection, all 3 types public private domain.
- put the files of your server (index.html, .htacces, and so on) in the folder whose address is in front of "Document root" in the browser page.

I think that's all.

Answer (score 0):

There are many layers of problems with the question you are asking but I'll attempt to answer your question.  If you are already connected to the WiFi using the iPad, that device should have a IP address automatically assigned by DHCP.  You should verify this first.  If you don't have an IP address assigned, then you should enable DHCP on the router and try again.

Once you have that part figured out, then you'll need to figure out what the IP address is assigned for the PC.  At the basic level of troubleshooting, try pinging the PC and see if you get a reply.  If you get a response, see if you can probe port 80 using telnet to see if the web server service is open and reachable.  If it is pingable and reachable by port 80, I'm guessing your problem is that the DNS name cannot be resolved (can be solved by entering in the IP address instead) or the URL you are trying is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tomorrow and report on the results here.

Comment: OK so I'm testing right now.
iPad got its IP 192.168.2.something
Router is in mode "DHCP (auto)"
PC got its IP 192.168.2.somethingelse too.

Comment: I think it worked. The problem may have been with how I opened the ports, but I'm not sure because there were many steps involved and I don't recall them all. I'll try to log as an answer to my own question all the steps, for future reference for people trying to do the same.
In any case thanks for your help :)